# Cannot delete custom resource definition which is from previous installation effect to new installations

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, devops

Previously created crds won't delete. still in the terminate state. any solution to delete this crds properly?

```
   Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): error when creating "elkkib.yml": create not allowed while custom resource definition is terminating
    
    Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): error when creating "elkkib.yml": create not allowed while custom resource definition is terminating
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this command：

```
kubectl patch crd/{your crd name} -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":[]}}' --type=merge
```

Refer to this：https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60538

Comment: Fantastic. I'm not the original poster but ran into this issue and this solution worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Took me way too long to find this. Thank you!